# Variability in k-means clusters results: setting set.seed() before?

Tags: r

Then I fit linear models to the `plot(n_clust, error)` aiming to identify the best combination of I'm trying to perform a k-means cluster on my data (matrix with 2000 cases and 10 variables). I don't know how many clusters should I choose. To solve this problem, I adopted a strategy in which different values of K are setted. Error results and the number of used clusters are stored in two vectors.

Then I fitted linear models that gives me the highest sum R-squared.
I used this strategy to choose de best K value. The point is that I have performed this process several times, noting that error vector varied between each run. This gave me different values of best K. An alternative to make k-means results "stable" is the use of `set.seed()` function prior `kmean()`. However I'm afraid that the result, despite fixed, have  no consistency.
Somebody could give me some "clues"? `set.seed()` will not just hind a variability? Is there another strategy for choosing the best K?

Thanks!

```
n_clust=NULL
error=NULL
for(i in 1:200){
cl <- kmeans(scores, i, iter.max=100)
erro <- c(error,cl$tot.withinss)
n_clust <- c(n_clust,i)
}

r2=NULL
for(i in 3:197){
a <- lm(error[1:i] ~ n_clust[1:i])
b <- lm(error[i+1:200] ~ n_clust[i+1:200])
rsqd <- as.numeric(summary.lm(a)[8]) + as.numeric(summary.lm(b)[8])
r2 <- c(r2, rsqd)}

id_n <- 3 + which(r2==max(r2))
```

Answer (score 7):

You say that `set.seed` doesn't work for you, but your example doesn't use `set.seed` so it's hard to know if you use it correctly!

This is an example close to yours that seem to work:

```
scores <- matrix(runif(1000), 100, 10)

set.seed(42)
k1 = kmeans(scores, 5, iter.max=500)

set.seed(42)
k2 = kmeans(scores, 5, iter.max=500)

identical(k1, k2) # TRUE
```

...note that you need to call `set.seed` with the same seed before calling `kmeans`, and you have to give *the same parameters* to `kmeans` if you want to expect the same answer.

When you specify an integer for the `centers` parameter, `kmeans` uses random numbers to come up with the centers. If you instead specify the centers your self, it should be reproducible. Here I choose the 5 first rows as centers (probably a bad idea though):

```
k1 = kmeans(scores, scores[1:5,], iter.max=500)
k2 = kmeans(scores, scores[1:5,], iter.max=500)
identical(k1, k2) # TRUE
```

Comment: adding to the answer. One usually runs K-means several times (e.g, 10) with differen seed and the same K, and uses the model with less error for each K.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Tommy's answer, 
To identify the optimal K value for your k-means cluster , the best method is to try Elbow curve, by plotting your withinss against your K value gives you the elbow curve and select the value at elbow as the optimal K value.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645895/calculating-the-percentage-of-variance-measure-for-k-means

https://www.r-bloggers.com/finding-optimal-number-of-clusters/